# Kotlin Error : Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.0.7

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I installed the Kotlin plugin into my app (v. v1.1.1-release-Studio2.2-1) and then selected "Configure Kotlin in Project"   I selected compiler and runtime version of 1.0.7. Kotlin updated my Gradle files. Now when I try to build in I get:

> Error: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
> Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.0.7.
> Required by:
>
> MyApplication:app:unspecified

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Post your project level `gradle`

Comment: This is how you add Kotlin support for Android: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html

Answer (score 238, accepted):

replace

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
                                                    ^
                                                    |
                                      JRE = Java Runtime Environment
```

with

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
                                                    ^
                                                    |
                                       JDK = Java Development Kit
```

Since the version with jre is absolute , just replace and sync the project

Official Documentation [here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#kotlin-standard-library-artifacts-and-split-packages) Thanks for the link @ [ROMANARMY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164966/r0manarmy)

Comment: Some helpful information in the [docs](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#kotlin-standard-library-artifacts-and-split-packages) about jdk and jre.

Comment: I believe one day Android team will make things a little easier not much just a little or at least they will write major changes in changelog with bold instead of burying it deep into the website to be mined out :))

Comment: It took me a full minute of staring to see the difference between `jre` and `jdk`—I must be getting old.

Comment: which file should i search for this?

Comment: funny I got the error that: Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10.

Answer (score 32):

In Project level `build.gradle` use only this version

> ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'

Remove other versions

This will only work with the latest version of android studio 3.4

> **UPDATE:** Try to use the latest version of kotlin with latest Android studio to avoid an error.

Comment: An answer that specifies a magic version to use, without explanation, is not all that helpful and becomes even less helpful over time.  Are you suggesting upgrading from a lower version?  Or downgrading from a higher version because the higher version has a bug?

Comment: @DonHatch this answer was given in March for android studio 2.2 which was getting error mention above in the question. It is not for android studio 3.0 or above.

Comment: @0xalihn answer below has a correct solution without magic version number

Comment: @PatelPinkal can you update your answer for latest android studio version.

Comment: @Arbaz.in try to install and use a new version of kotlin. May its help you. Also, note that your studio should be the latest version if you are using latest kotlin version.

Comment: @PatelPinkal Sure ill do same

Comment: Ok, If it's working then edit this post or provide your answer here. So, others can have solutions.

Comment: i updated answer as per latest version of Android studio

Comment: @Arbaz.in I can't see any update in answer. Please post your answer in a comment

Answer (score 32):

If you hereafter removing Jcenter from Gradle then add this to your gradle

```
repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }



allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

So main point is that, add  `mavenCentral()` and `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` in gradle

Comment: Thanks. Only needed `mavenCentral()` for me (to replace `jcenter()`)

Answer (score 24):

The split of `kotlin-stdlib` into `kotlin-stdlib-jre7` and `kotlin-stdlib-jre8` was only introduced with Kotlin 1.1, that's why the dependency cannot be resolved, the package version simply does not exist.

It looks like the update to your project files failed at some point and set the Kotlin version to 1.0.7. If this is a new project and there's nothing holding you back from using 1.1.1, I'd switch to that. Your problem should be gone after doing this.

Comment: Thank you for explaining.  Several answers say use 1.1.1 without explanation, which will make the answers rapidly become useless in the future.

Answer (score 12):

In "build.gradle" file, change current Kotlin version that line and press synk:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.1'
```

/// That will look like:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.1'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Starting with Kotlin 1.1.2, the dependencies with group `org.jetbrains.kotlin` are by default resolved with the version taken from the applied plugin. You can provide the version manually using the full dependency notation like:

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
```

If you're targeting JDK 7 or JDK 8, you can use extended versions of the Kotlin standard library which contain additional extension functions for APIs added in new JDK versions. Instead of kotlin-stdlib, use one of the following dependencies:

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7"
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
```

Answer (score 11):

A new solution if you use Android Studio 3.2, I solved this issue by added mavenCentral() to build.gradle of the project:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

You should add the line as this order, the credited is for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49552433)

Answer (score 5):

```
buildscript {
    **ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.1'**  //Add this line
    repositories {
        **jcenter()**                 //Add this line
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        **jcenter()**                 //Add this line
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could elaborate on how this improves Mihail Salari's answer, on which it seems to be based.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this issue using deselection of the **Offline work** option in `Settings`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Android Studio 3.2 & above,then issue will be solved by adding google() & jcenter() to build.gradle of the project:

```
repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me:
Using Gradle 4.8.1

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.1' 
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'}
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev/'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Please check current version of your Kotlin in below path,

   C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\org\jetbrains\kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.0.5

change to that version `(1.0.5)` in project level gradle file.

You can see in your above path does not mentioned any Java - `jre version`, so remove in your app level gradle file as below,

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
```

Answer (score 1):

### build.gradle (Project)

```
buildScript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-rc01'
    }
}
```

### gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

```
...
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

---

Some libraries require the **updated gradle**. Such as:

```
androidTestImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$coroutines"
```

GL

Answer (score 1):

This issue occured when I updated from Electric eel to Falmingo.
I solved it like this:

Goto File->Project Structure-> SDK Location -> JDK (Gradle Settings)

In the Gradle JDK drop down, **choose Embedded JDK** (Try diffrent options if this does not work, preferably the latest JDK)

Now try sync project with gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

In case a (transitive) dependency still uses the `jre` variant of the Kotlin library, you can force the use of the `jdk` variant with the help of a resolution strategy:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            details.requested.with {
                if (group == "org.jetbrains.kotlin" && name.startsWith("kotlin-stdlib-jre")) {
                    details.useTarget(group: group, name: name.replace("jre", "jdk"), version: version)
                    details.because("Force use of 'kotlin-stdlib-jdk' in favor of deprecated 'kotlin-stdlib-jre'.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the build.gradle version, It started working
4.0.0 to 3.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Reload sdk maybe the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing issues with your Flutter project, updating Gradle could be a solution. Here are the steps you can follow:

1. Open your **build.gradle(app)** file and update the following line of code under the dependencies section:

> dependencies {
> implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0"

2. Next, open your build.gradle(android) file and update the following line of code under the dependencies section:

> classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0"

By making these updates, you should be able to resolve any issues related to Gradle and successfully run your Flutter project. Remember to always keep your dependencies up to date to ensure the smooth running of your project.

Answer (score 0):

I put my experience here in case someone knows the reason why (2) worked. This happened to me twice with the same project:

(1) I cloned a flutter project and successfully built it. But the second time I tried to build it again, this error happened. Tried this and that, nothing worked. Then I deleted and cloned the project again, built it, and it successfully ran.

(2) Still using the very same re-cloned project in (1), after 3 days it worked wonderfully, in fourth day it suddenly happened again. I simply opened Android Studio and trying to run the app, and it happened again. This time, I saw Changes (in commit window) in files and the only file related with project setting was `pubspec.lock`. I deleted it, rebuilt, and it successfully ran.

Answer (score -1):

Simple Steps:

1. Click File > Project Structure
2. Click Dependencies >
   Find and Click org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.21 (or whatever your current version is)
3. Under Details > update section, click [update variable][update
   dependencies]
4. Click Ok

Answer (score -2):

In my case problem solved by adding the following lines in `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
            jcenter()                
            google()
         maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } //remember to add this line
  }
}
```