# Error:Unable to resolve version for dependency 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:jar'

Tags: kotlin

I have a project written in java I am integrating kotlin with using gradle.  I am trying to follow https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html

My build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
}
apply plugin: "kotlin"
dependencies {
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7"
}
```

according to [Kotlin Error : Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.0.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42843441/kotlin-error-could-not-find-org-jetbrains-kotlinkotlin-stdlib-jre71-0-7) the library is only available in kotlin v1.1 and up.  When I deploy this library and use it in my android project I get the error in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to replace

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7"
```

with

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Kotlin 1.1.2 and if you're targeting JDK 7 or JDK 8, you can use extended versions of the Kotlin standard library which contain additional extension functions for APIs added in new JDK versions. 
Use one of the following dependencies:

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7"
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
```