# Gradle sync failed: Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin (no intention to use Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin, canary-deployment

(not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42843441/kotlin-error-could-not-find-org-jetbrains-kotlinkotlin-stdlib-jre71-0-7) in my opinion)

Error message in Android Studio:

> Gradle sync failed: Could not find
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3-2

I do not understand why Gradle will not sync without this library, and why Kotlin is mandatory. Also, I have not tried or intended to install or use the Kotlin plugin.

Note: This occurred just after I have upgraded to the latest Android Canary version just now on the dev update channel. There was no issue or anything Kotlin related in the stable version or in my code itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After update to Android studio 3.1 i'm facing this erorr Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534872/after-update-to-android-studio-3-1-im-facing-this-erorr-could-not-find-org-jetb)

Comment: I'm marking this as a duplicate since the other question has working answers (even though it's newer than this one).

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem too. So I found the **Project SDK** is missing in **Project Structure**. So I change it to the recommend item (jdk1.8..., etc)
[image]

Hope this match your case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and updating the version from JetBrains' site fixed it

In the file `build.gradle(project:)`;

Either

- in "ext" section, as a number in a variable (probably like `kotlin_version`)

Or

- it might be in the "dependencies" section, simply in the end of the `classpath` declaration

Link:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#plugin-and-versions