# After update to Android Studio 3.1 I'm facing this error: Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

After updating to Android Studio 3.1, I'm facing this error.

Note: I'm using Java not Kotlin

```
Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.0.

Searched in the following locations:
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre8/1.2.0/kotlin-stdlib-jre8-1.2.0.pom
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre8/1.2.0/kotlin-stdlib-jre8-1.2.0.jar
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre8/1.2.0/kotlin-stdlib-jre8-1.2.0.pom
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre8/1.2.0/kotlin-stdlib-jre8-1.2.0.jar
Required by:
    project :app > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.0
    project :app > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.0
    project :app > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.0
    project :app > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.1.0
    project :app > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.0 > com.android.databinding:compilerCommon:3.1.0
    project :app > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.1.0
    project :app > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.1.0
    project :app > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.1.0 > com.android.tools:repository:26.1.0
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49096658/3806413

Comment: @0xalihn Thanks,You made my day.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote if it works. So that, others can be benefited.

Comment: Sorry i need 15 reputation to upvote comments.

Comment: This may be worth checking also - worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49510827/334402

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Working like this

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.1'  //Add this line
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

JCenter was being cranky the other day, so following should help:

```
    repositories {
        mavenCentral() // <-- add this at top
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
```

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I dunno man but apparently it solved the issue for me and 8 other people who upvoted it? Technically it's because jCenter was overloaded, so moving it to the bottom and adding mavenCentral at the top makes Gradle look for it in mavenCentral first, and jCenter second. If it's not overloaded at the time, the order shouldn't affect anything, though. If this is not the cause, I'd put my wager on `implementation` vs `api` in Gradle build dependency.

Comment: This is solved my problem, thank you @EpicPandaForce for that great answer.
By the way my problem was - problem occurred configuring root project could not get resource kotlin plugin 1.3.0 on Android Studio 3.2.1

Answer (score 7):

Add the JCenter repo to your Project-level `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        repositories {
            //...
            google()
            jcenter() // <--- this is needed
        }

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your Project gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    }
}
```