# Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1

Tags: android, gradle

my Android Studio project does not load this is the problem:

> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar

And my build.gradle is:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

please help, thank you

Comment: Did you opened AS in administrator mode then tried to open it in normal mode (if not, don't do it) ? This is know to be a problem, else it might just be due to an installation problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `jcenter()` with `google()` in repositories and allprojects->repositories blocks in build.gradle

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: probably not related, I guess, but after I tried this, I had another problem, which seems to have been solved by this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49552433/1432736

Answer (score 0):

Add both `jcenter()` and `google()` in repositories and `allprojects->repositories` blocks in `build.gradle`. Mine looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    }
}
```

This is very similiar to ashazar's answer. For me instead of replacing `jcenter()` with `google()`, I needed both `jcenter()` and `google()`.