# Gradle sync failed: Could not HEAD 'jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/…'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Tags: android, android-studio

Gradle sync failed: Could not HEAD 'jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/…'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

I cannot able to run Application in Android Studio.

[image: Please click this for Image]

Below is the Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.XX.XX">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:node="merge"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".PrinterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PrinterWebViewActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

After "Sync Project with Gradle Files" below exception coming
Gradle sync failed: Could not HEAD 'jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/…'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

I have tried to check online but couldn't find solution.Please help me on this.Thanks in Advance

Comment: restart your android studio

Comment: You need to select module that you want to run from dropdown on the left of run button

Comment: Hi, I have tried but didn't work. May you help me on this please

Comment: @KaranMehta, App module is not showing, it is showing only "EditConfigurations" option

Comment: Share code of your AndroidManifest file

Comment: @KaranMehta, added Manifest file, May you please check it and let me know.

Comment: Are you running app on emulator or device?

Comment: @OsamaAftab, No I am running app on physical device through USB.Other projects are working fine except this Project.

Comment: What exactly is happening? Is app getting installed but not launching?

Comment: Cannot able to run, RUN option is disabled

Comment: package="com.XX.XX"  is this a right package name of your project?

Comment: it is right package, because of confidential issues I renamed Package name as com.XX.XX here

Comment: Try "Sync project with gradle files" in file menu

Comment: @KaranMehta, after syncing project with gradle files -- Gradle sync failed: Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.50/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.50.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1 m 33 s 364 ms)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54646356/10075771 try this solution if its work for you, there's something missing in your kotlin repo i think

Comment: I have checked specified link but it didn't work out.Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, 
To run any module or application it should be visible in an app  or run module section where we generally see the app module,

So there are lots of reasons why module  not visible in that section which is bellow

- First code run configuration not properly visible,
- Another one is problem in the build
- Also maybe problem in Gradle file
- If the code is copied from another place and you are synching with local Gradle then may be problem
- May be module not defined in `settings.gradle`  file

What we can do?

- First check `settings.gradle` the file is module defined in or included in file bellow `include ':app'` if yes then check configuration section then after check above section one by one.
- Also if any catching related problem then just select `Invalidate Caches/Restart` from the file menu and try to rebuild.

Answer (score -1):

try Build - > clean project 
after project cleanded again Build - > rebuild project

if this does not work than try File - > cache and restart