# ANDROID: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Cannot find a version of 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib' that satisfies the version constraints

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I tried running a test class and i caught this build error below. It only appears when trying to run test(s) and not when building&running app. Any suggestions on how to resolve this? I am not using kotlin in my app at all.

```
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskDependencyResolveException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.TaskDependencyResolver.resolveDependenciesFor(TaskDependencyResolver.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.getDependencies(LocalTaskNode.java:106)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.resolveDependencies(LocalTaskNode.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.addEntryTasks(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:167)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.addEntryTasks(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:139)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry.withLenientState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:132)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry.withLenientState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$CalculateTaskGraph.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:333)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.constructTaskGraph(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:218)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:155)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1175)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$2100(DefaultConfiguration.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationTaskDependency.visitDependencies(DefaultConfiguration.java:1657)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext$TaskGraphImpl.getNodeValues(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker$GraphWithEmpyEdges.getNodeValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:211)
    at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.doSearch(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.findValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:66)
    ... 105 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}.
Required by:
    project :app
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.EdgeState.failWith(EdgeState.java:155)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.attachFailureToEdges(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:382)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.validateGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:326)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:133)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:171)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$7.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:580)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:571)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$600(DefaultConfiguration.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$6.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:551)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$SafeExclusiveLockImpl.withLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:244)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveExclusively(DefaultConfiguration.java:547)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:542)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$2200(DefaultConfiguration.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationResolvableDependencies.assertArtifactsResolved(DefaultConfiguration.java:1409)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationResolvableDependencies.access$3500(DefaultConfiguration.java:1297)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationResolvableDependencies$LenientResolutionResult.resolve(DefaultConfiguration.java:1424)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationResolvableDependencies$LenientResolutionResult.getAllComponents(DefaultConfiguration.java:1461)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.ConstraintHandler.execute(ConstraintHandler.kt:38)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.ConstraintHandler.execute(ConstraintHandler.kt:31)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$2.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.beforeResolve(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.performPreResolveActions(DefaultConfiguration.java:633)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$800(DefaultConfiguration.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$7.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:578)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:571)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$600(DefaultConfiguration.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$6.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:551)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$SafeExclusiveLockImpl.withLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:244)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveExclusively(DefaultConfiguration.java:547)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:542)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphForBuildDependenciesIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:692)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$3700(DefaultConfiguration.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationTaskDependency.visitDependencies(DefaultConfiguration.java:1652)
    ... 110 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Cannot find a version of 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib' that satisfies the version constraints: 
   Dependency path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding3:rxbinding:3.0.0-alpha2' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.71'
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Dependency path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha04' --> 'androidx.room:room-migration:2.1.0-alpha04' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.0'
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71
   Constraint path 'App:app:unspecified' --> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.2.71}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.2.71

    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.validateGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:325)
    ... 164 more
```

Comment: Upgrade the Kotlin used in your Gradle build files to at least `1.3.0`. The latest is `1.3.30`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks! If you want, could you reply as answer so I could upvote&accept for future refence if anyone else might end up with same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some libraries will require particular versions of Kotlin, typically if they depend upon newer language features (e.g., coroutines in Kotlin 1.3).

In your case, `androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha04`, through its `androidx.room:room-migration:2.1.0-alpha04` dependency, wants Kotlin 1.3.0 or higher, but your project is set for Kotlin 1.2.71.

The typically-simple solution is to bump your Kotlin version. In a typical current Android Studio project, that is set in an `ext.kotlin_version` line in the `buildscript` closure of the top-level `build.gradle` file. Otherwise, hunt around your Gradle build scripts and properties files, looking for `1.2.71`. Replace it with `1.3.0` or higher — as of late April 2019, the latest production Kotlin version is 1.3.30.

If upgrading your Kotlin version causes other problems, such as failed tests, you could elect to downgrade the dependencies that are calling for the higher Kotlin version. Eventually, though, you will want to resolve the problems and get on a current Kotlin version.

Comment: Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should update the gradle distribution to `6.1.1` and the dependency of the project.

Check the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61981410/5279996

GL