# change implementation Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.21

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]can't sync gradle (Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.21.), and the answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53358817/8571964) was [replace

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

with

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"]

but i couldn't find where is this implementation
by the way, i am not even using kotlin

Comment: first of ll which language are you using java or kotlin ?

Comment: actually i am using cordova and capacitorjs

Comment: when i move the project from capacitor to the AS i keep getting dependencies erros to things that i am not even using

Answer (score 0):

[image]    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8
compile group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-stdlib-jdk8', version: '1.3.31'

current Kotlin version is 1.3.72 for more information follow above link

add jcenter to repositories

```
Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.21.
Searched in the following locations:
  - file:/C:/Users/i.tech/.android/manual-offline-m2/android-gradle-plugin-3.5.0-beta01/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.21/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.21.pom
  - file:/C:/Users/i.tech/.android/manual-offline-m2/android-gradle-plugin-3.5.0-beta01/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.21/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.21.jar
  - file:/C:/Users/i.tech/.android/manual-offline-m2/gmaven_stable/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.21/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.21.pom
  - file:/C:/Users/i.tech/.android/manual-offline-m2/gmaven_stable/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.21/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.21.jar
  - https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.21/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.21.pom
  - https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.21/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.21.jar
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.21/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.21.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.21/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.21.jar
Required by:
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.0
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.4.0
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.4.0
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.4.0
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:3.4.0
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.4.0
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.0 > com.android.tools:common:26.4.0
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.4.0
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:26.4.0
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.4.0 > com.android.tools:repository:26.4.0
```

Comment: in what file ? folder?

Comment: You want to know Kotlin library(arr) files on developer machine?

Comment: can you clarify the answer

Comment: i am not using kotlin im my project or on my machine

Comment: I am answering according to android studio adding Kotlin dependency. To add dependency in your application module put this line in app level build.gradle file  in dependency section "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.71".

Comment: If you are not using Kotlin then remove Kotlin plugins from app build gradle file and remove dependency also

Comment: glad to, HOW,  Note my connection is realey slow so it take some time till i respond

Comment: added an image of the project