# Android (Java) application error on first build "Could not find kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.72.jar"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to create a simple web view application. This is my first time on Android Studio.

I get the following error immediately after creating the project:

```
    Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 1 s 429 ms

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.72).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.3.72/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.72.jar
   > Could not find kotlin-stdlib-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.72).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.72/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.72.jar

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1qM9.png)

The thing that confuses me is that I'm not even using Kotlin.

I tried googling it but all the responses didn't seem to address my issue or I didn't understand them. What am I missing here?

*Note*: I don't know if this has to do with anything but it seemed to be working on my first project. Android Studio was downloading something but I accidentally force quitted it and it became like this.

Comment: your question is duplicated, please search it first, your answer is this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53358817/7138532

Comment: @HamedKarami thanks for your comment. I'm pretty new to Android Studio and don't know where to replace "implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version""

Comment: I couldn't find it in the build.gradle file. I'm not even using Kotlin.

Comment: I think when you were creating a new project, the default value was kotlin, try to create a new one and select java in the language field.

Comment: And another way, about the implementation, find build.gradle file, add or replace this line in dependencies scope. implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version" , you see this link too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43159281/7138532

Comment: I tried that but what fixed it was putting maven-central on the dependency list